# Loop through values of object which is property of another object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, loops

I have 2 Objects, User and Menu, I want to loop into User.Menu to creat links like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < _Usuario.Menu.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.ActionLink( Convert.ToString(_Usuario.Menu.LinkName), Convert.ToString(_Usuario.Menu.ActionName),                    Convert.ToString(_Usuario.Menu.ControllerName))
}
```

But i dont have a counter for User.Menu, how could this be done ?

```
public class User
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }
    public Menu Menu { get; set; }
    public List<string> Objects { get; set; }
    public List<string> Controllers { get; set; }
    //public List<string> Roles { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Objects = new List<string>();
        Controllers = new List<string>();
    }
}

public class Menu
{
    public List<string> LinkName { get; set; }
    public List<string> ActionName { get; set; }
    public List<string> ControllerName { get; set; }

    public Menu()
    {
        LinkName = new List<string>();
        ActionName = new List<string>();
        ControllerName = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu class doesn't make much sense as it implies that the link, action, and controller names are three separate sets of items. In reality there is a single set of menu items each consisting of a link, action, and controller. So this means you can rewrite Menu as:

```
public class Menu
{
    public List<MenuItem> Items { get; set; }

    public Menu()
    {
        Items = new List<MenuItem>();
    }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public string LinkName { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
}
```

You'll have to rewrite your code that sets up menu, but that should be easy enough.
Then it is easy to loop through in your view.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < _Usuario.Menu.Items.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(_Usuario.Menu.Items[i].LinkName, _Usuario.Menu.Items[i].ActionName, _Usuario.Menu.Items[i].ControllerName)
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to see a `foreach` rather than this way, but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to create a display template for the model and use `@Html.DisplayFor()`.  This way you do not need to worry about the loop as it will do it for you.   This is a good way to keep your razor view nice and clean.

**Example**

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string LinkName { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
}
```

Display template (menuitem.cshtml):

```
@model MenuItem

@Html.ActionLink(Model.LinkName, Model.ActionName, Model.ControllerName)
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MenuItem>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```